# react-native headerTitleStyle

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using the StackNavigator and was trying to align the word 'topic' to center vertically. However, adjusting padding and margin does not seem to help. I believe the space above the word is to cater to the status bar. Is there a way around this? The StackNavigator code is below.

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nkksj.png)

```
export const MyAppStack = StackNavigator({
  Topic: {
    screen: TopicScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Topic',
      headerStyle: { 
        backgroundColor: 'grey', 
        elevation: null,
        paddingTop: 0,
        height: 10,
        marginTop: 0 },
      headerTitleStyle: {
        paddingTop: 0,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
      }
    },
  },
  FlashCard: {
    screen: FlashCardScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Flashcards',
      headerBackTitleStyle: {
        fontSize: 100,
        alignSelf: 'center'
      }
    },
  },
});
```

I am also attaching the header style (the top portion) for reference but I don't think the problems lies with it. Thanks in advance!

```
const Header = (props) => {
  const { textStyle, viewStyle } = styles;

  return (
    <View style={viewStyle}>
      <Text style={textStyle}>{props.headerText}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = {
  viewStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#ff8a00',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: 60,
    paddingTop: 15,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.2,
    elevation: 2,
    position: 'relative'
  },
  textStyle: {
    fontSize: 20
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove *alignSelf: 'center'* from ...

`headerTitleStyle: {
        paddingTop: 0,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
      }`